# Style rule based on qgsfunction not working in QGIS 3.22 #92

Tags: qgis, labeling, symbology, rule-based, qgsexpression

I'm using a QGIS style based on a function which returns the value of a layer variable passed through a pyqgis plugin :

```
@qgsfunction(args="auto", group="toto")
def color_trajecto(feature, parent, context):
    color = context.variable("color")
    return color if color else "#ff0000"
```

Then I put this as entry of an expression for filling the color of my symbol as shown below :
[image: 2022-06-21 10_39_41-Éditer une règle]

Default value is red, but I passed blue and it is well detected in the filling color bar on its left. But above the color is not taken into account and the symbol as well. This code is working until QGIS 3.16 therefore I presume it's an issue of 3.22.

When I pass directly the variable `color` it's working but this variable is initialized by the user that's why I use a function to test its existence.